# get public key from private key with python OpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

Well, I generate a private key with pyOpenSSL as follows:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
k = crypto.PKey()
k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
print crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k)
```

How do I get the public key string from it? I've still not found what method of this library does it. Thanks

Comment: You appear to have printed it in the last line of your code.  As @danodonovan says below.  Edit: sorry, not paying attention.

Comment: I print the private key, but I need the public one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
cert = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k)
```

doesn't do what you want, then it doesn't look like `pyOpenSSL` supports public key dumping. There is an unmerged branch [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~shanemhansen/pyopenssl/dump_publickey) that adds that functionality but I can't claim that it does what is purports.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
Now it has the method to get public key directly.

```
key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
publickey_contents = crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)
```

with the method `dump_publickey` you can get what you want.